# encontrar comentarios en archivo de texto java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas me gustaría explicarles mi problema a ver si pueden ayudarme pasa que estoy leyendo un archivo de texto en java, lo que pasa con esto es que en el archivo yo debo detectar comentarios que llevarían este formato

**(***

Comentario

***)**

cómo ven el formato sera que siempre el que inicia (* comienza en una línea y el que termina lo hace igual en una unica línea.

y siempre sigue ese formato.

estoy haciendo este código donde encuentro el primer (* y mi idea es imprimir el comentario hasta que el while encuentre al segundo *) que es donde tendría que parar, pero entra en un bucle interminable

```
                if (lineaLeerTXT.equals("(*")) {
                    
                    while (lineaLeerTXT.equals("*)")) {
                        
                        System.out.println(lineaLeerTXT);
                        
                    }
                }
```

sinceramente no entiendo porque como menciono mi idea es encontrar al primer (* y luego con un while ciclo para encontrar al segundo y se acabe hasta que el while se detenga pero siento que me falta mucho mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez te sirva como inspiración lo siguiente:

```
int h = 0;
boolean leer = false;
String lineas[] = textoGuardado.split( "\n" );  
String comentarios[] = new String[ lineas ];
for( int i = 0; i < lineas.length; i ++ ) {
    if( leer ) {
        comentarios[ h ] = lineas[ i ];
        h++;
    }
    if( lineas[ i ].equals( "(*" )) {
        leer = true;
    }
    else if( lineas[ i ].equals( "*)" )) {
        leer = false;
    }
}
```

Primero creamos un array con **split( "\n" );**, que lo que hace es cortar el texto en los saltos de linea (\n).
Creamos otro array de igual dimensión, para guardar los comentarios.
La variable **h** con la que vamos a recorrer el array de comentarios, y un boleano que nos va a indicar cuando estamos ante uno.
Dentro del for, primero verificamos si **leer** es verdadero, en cuyo caso guardamos la linea en **comentarios**, y aumentamos en 1 **h**.
Con el siguiente bloque if/else if, verificamos si estamos ante un comienzo de comentario o un final, variando el valor de **leer** en consecuencia.

Comment: muchas gracias lo analizare te lo agradezco

Comment: me ayudaste un montón muchas gracias, la verdad el código no me salió igual al tuyo, pero con el tuyo me hice una buena idea de cómo debería quedar y así lo logré hacer jejej muchas gracias

Comment: @EstherPorta, un placer ayudarte!!